# Sleeping and printing without newline?

Tags: python

If I run this code:

```
for x in range(10):
    time.sleep(1)
    print("a")
```

It will do exactly what it should. But if I run this:

```
for x in range(10):
    time.sleep(1)
    print("a", end="")
```

It will wait the entire 10 seconds and then print the 10 `a`'s.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: Definitely not a library bug. Always assume your own code is at fault first (it's seen a lot less testing).  The problem is that [`stdout` is line-buffered](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/).

Comment: @JonathonReinhart that certainly seems logical, but this behavior seemed really eratic. Having to flush stdout certainly doesn't seem very "Python". They're probably very rare, but I have encountered bugs in the standard Python libraries before (zipfile in 2.6, apparently infamous)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Flush stdout after print.

```
import time
import sys

for x in range(10):
    time.sleep(1)
    print("a", end="")
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

---

Python 3.3 [print](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function has optional `flush` parameter; You can write as follow in Python 3.3+.

```
import time

for x in range(10):
    time.sleep(1)
    print("a", end="", flush=True)
```